# Meaning of "is getting on me.."?

Tags: idioms, expressions

What's the meaning of "is getting on me"? For example:

> "Mom is always **getting on me** about not finishing my breakfast."

Comment: The fourth entry under **get on (someone or something)** from [this dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+on) might have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, a question like this might be closed as [entirely answerable by a dictionary](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/policy-for-questions-that-are-entirely-answerable-with-a-dictionary). However, this particular phrase might be very hard to find in a [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-on), so I don't think this particular question fits that close reason.

This is an informal, shortened form for **getting on someone's back**. This idiom is defined by Macmillan as:

> [**on someone's back**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/on-someone-s-back) (*phrase*) `informal` always criticizing someone, or always telling them to do things : *You’re always on my back about something*.

So, we could express your sentence as:

> "Mom is always getting on my back about not finishing my breakfast."

but sometimes the *on my back* might be shortened even further:

> "Mom is always getting on me about not finishing my breakfast."